# Cannot install package from a private GitHub repository via poetry

Tags: pip, python-poetry

The package repo contains `pyproject.toml` with `[tool.poetry.dependencies]` section but without `[project].dependencies`.

Initially, I tried to install it pip. But it didn't install the sub-dependencies specified in its `[tool.poetry.dependencies]`.

Then I tried to `poetry add git+https://<username>:<token>@github.com/<username>/<package>.git` which gets the error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host=‘<username>’, port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /<token>@github.com/<username>/<package>.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x1139c84d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))
```

I'm doing it in CI/CD flow, thus, I do not wish to use ssh access. And I prefer not to modify package's `pyproject.toml` or add `setup.py` to it. The most desirable way is to install package with its subdependencies from private repository with poetry.